# tr [:upper:] [:lower:] with Cyrillic text

Tags: shell, unicode, tr

I'm trying to extract a word list from a Russian short story.

```
#!/bin/sh

export LC_ALL=ru_RU.utf8

sed -re 's/\s+/\n/g' | \
sed 's/[\.!,—()«»;:?]//g' | \
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | \
sort | uniq
```

However the `tr` step is not lowercasing the Cyrillic capital letters. I thought I was being clever using the portable character classes!

```
$ LC_ALL=ru_RU.utf8 echo "Г" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
Г
```

In case it's relevant, I obtained the Russian text by copy-pasting from a Chrome browser window into Vim. It looks right on screen (a Putty terminal). This is in Cygwin's bash shell -- it should work identically to Bash on Linux (should!).

What is a portable, reliable way to lowercase unicode text in a pipe?

Comment: Conversion with `sed` works for me: `echo 'СТЭК' | sed 's/[[:upper:]]*/\L&/'`

Comment: `echo "Г" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` outputs "г" properly on a Mac OS X 10.8 system.

Comment: Thanks @LevLevitsky . That's a suitable fix for me (feel free to promote it into an answer). I wonder why tr doesn't work.

Comment: @ulidtko Interesting, what version of `tr` is it?

Comment: OSX tr is BSD tr. The manpage says that historically LC_ALL was ignored, and now it is not. I guess that implies unicode is supported. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tr.1.html

Comment: `uname | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"` output `Linlx` on openwrt. tr is busybox 1.34.1

Comment: per macos mapage
     The LANG, LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE environment variables affect
     the execution of tr as described in environ(7).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what I found at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) (without any reference, though):

> Most versions of `tr`, including `GNU tr` and classic Unix `tr`, operate on single-byte characters and are not Unicode compliant. An exception is the [Heirloom Toolchest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heirloom_Project) implementation, which provides basic Unicode support.

Also, [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-coreutils@gnu.org/msg16642.html) is old but related.

As I mentioned in the comment, `sed` seems to work (`GNU sed`, at least):

```
$ echo 'СТЭК' | sed 's/[[:upper:]]*/\L&/'
стэк
```

Comment: Yes, the single-byte issue is true. I once reported this as a bug to GNU and they explained this is so by design (i.e. they would have to break compatibility with old software in order to fix it). I also discussed it on a mailing list and was similarly [told it was supposed to be that way](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2004-10/msg00063.html).

Comment: Remember to add g flag to the regular expression, if you want to replace all occurrences.

Comment: If you add a space to the beginning, it will not work: `echo ' СТЭК' | sed 's/[[:upper:]]*/\L&/'` => ' СТЭК'. It seems this one works better: `echo ' СТЭК' | sed 's/.*/\L&/'` => ' стэк'. Tested on GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Just need to add g: 's/[[:upper:]]*/\L&/g'

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
echo ЫЕРУНКЫКТ | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'
```